# Multi level cache access time

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, multi-level

If there are 2 caches L1 and L2 where L1 is first level cache and L2 is lower level cache.
Suppose there is a miss in L1 and a hit in L2. 
Now, do we need to bring the required block from L2 to L1 and then access the required byte from L1 or can we directly access the required byte from L2?

Average access time can be given as :- h1(t1) + (1-h1)(h2)(t1+t2) where

h1 : hit ratio of L1 cache,
t1  : access time of L1,
h2 : hit ratio of L2 cache ,
t2 : access time of L2.

Answer (score 1):

We can access it directly from L2, but we will also bring it up into L1, so that next time it is accessed faster.

Comment: So why do we add the time t1 again when we try to access from L2 during L1 miss? It should be only t2 right as we can directly access from L2

Comment: Well, that depends on the architecture. Newer architectures go to all levels of cache at the same time, so you don't have to pay that time penalty and you just apply t2. In older architectures, you would check L1 first, then if it wasn't there, you would check L2. Thus you would have to pay the time penalty for both.

Comment: t1 here is not the checking time I guess. It's the time required to read a byte .

Comment: What kind of newer architectures do you mean? Almost everything I know of accesses L2 only on L1 misses. It kinda beats the purpose otherwise, you want to sustain higher BW when running from the L1 than what the L2 allows you